# No crit high low returned by sensors - is this normal?

Tags: cpu, hardware, sensors

I assembled a brand new Ryzen-based workstation. The temperature sensors returned by `sensors` seems to be working fine, but those of the CPU do not specify low, crit, and high thresholds.

```
> sensors
nvme-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +36.9°C  (low  = -20.1°C, high = +74.8°C)
                       (crit = +79.8°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +47.8°C  
Tdie:         +47.8°C  
Tccd1:        +31.8°C  
Tccd2:        +31.8°C
```

Is this normal? Should I set this manually somewhere? What are acceptable temperature ranges for these 3 sensors? I am using debian bullseye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lm-sensors comes with the only configuration file `/etc/sensors3.conf` which has some definitions (allowed minimums and maximums) for certain chips.

Since lm-sensors has no way of knowing which exact AMD K10 compatible CPU you're running, they cannot add it to the configuration which works for everyone. Probably you can find allowences on the net and add them to e.g. `/etc/sensors.d/k10temp.conf`

```
chip "k10temp-*"
     set in1_min  ?
     set in1_max ?
     set in2_min  ?
     set in2_max ?
     set in3_min  ?
     set in3_max ?
     set in4_min  ?
     set in4_max ?
```

You can check `/etc/sensors3.conf` or https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/tree/master/configs

There's no need to actually specify mins and maxs because modern CPUs have safeguards against overheating and I believe you're not going to use liquid nitrogen to freeze your CPU.

Comment: No liquid nitrogen indeed! Good to know that OS-independent safeguards exists. Nevertheless, since I am not very experienced in assembling PC parts, I'll keep an eye on those sensors, especially since I am doing CPU-intensive multithreaded numerical simulations. Thanks.

Comment: I managed to label sensors differently using `label temp1 "OTHERNAME"` but unfortunately my `set temp1_max 90` statements seems to be ignored. If you have any clue why, please share.

Comment: @nicoco Please post a bug report here https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/issues - it will be closed for sure, but developers will let you know what's wrong and how to remedy it. I don't know any other way of contacting them infortunately. Maybe a mailing list but I've never used it. As far as I can see people use their issue tracker exactly this way, e.g. https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/issues/137

Comment: I've filed an issue because it's interesting for me as well: https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/issues/339